# Как сделать так, чтобы всплывающая информация при наведении курсором на точку отображалась для всех точек, которые накладываются друг на друга

Tags: python, plotly

Нужно сделать так,чтобы hover отображалась для всех точек, которые накладываются друг на друга, а не только для последней.

```
#Hover отображается только для верхней точки
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2,1,2],
    y=[3, 3, 3,3,3],
    mode="markers",
 text = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3','m4','m5']
)
             )
fig.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже попробовал для каждой точки делать свой трейс add_trace(go.Scatter( c последующим  fig.update_layout(hovermode='x') Это работает, но ужасно выглядит когда много точек, так как вылетают все ховеры по наведенной курсором оси x.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять параметры layout:

```
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x")
```

или

```
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
```

Comment: fig.update_layout(hovermode="x") я пробовал, это не то что нужно    

fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")  - не работает: 
``` Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'hovermode' property of layout
        Received value: 'x unified'

    The 'hovermode' property is an enumeration that may be specified as:
      - One of the following enumeration values:
            ['x', 'y', 'closest', False]```